# Why am I getting payouts from 6 blocks with only 1 share found with a LTC P2Pool pool?

Tags: transactions, litecoin, p2pool, pool-payout-methods

I was mining in a LTC P2Pool pool and found a share.
As I understand it, if the conditions outlined in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12797/why-is-my-p2pool-share-not-payed-out) would have been satisfied, I should have received a payout from the next block found by the P2Pool network. As a matter of fact, It seems I [received](http://explorer.litecoin.net/address/LW9y3UiicfRPBZcniMrCrVhHnR2ygnWVe9) a payout from the next *six* blocks (from 414890 to 415003).

I failed to find the rationale behind this. Could you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payout method in p2pool is based on [PPLNS](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=39832). In this method, every share is rewarded for each block found within the next N shares. Depending on the exact value of N and the luck in finding blocks by the pool, this can mean several blocks.